# Write a redirect rule to .htaccess with %

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to write a RewriteRule so that I can redirect a url like

```
http://example.com/cont.php?fdsfsd=fdsfsd
```

To a url with a param that has the character %3 like:

```
http://example.com/another.php?var=ntvpz2hrzm0&cof=FORID%3dsa
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a backslash in front of the %

```
RewriteRule cont.php another.php?var=ntvpz2hrzm0&cof=FORID\%3dsa [R=301,NE,L]
```

The NE flag may also be necessary to prevent later processes from attempting to escape the % sign.